# How to check HDFS SafeMode status through WebHDFS?

Tags: hadoop, webhdfs

Is there any RestAPIs available to check the safemode status of HDFS? Currently using the below command to get the status?

```
hadoop dfsadmin -safemode get
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can see safemode status in WebUI

```
http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.jsp
```

underneath **Cluster Summary**